# Dynamically Change A CSS Class's attributes in C#

Tags: c#, css, class

I want to be able to "A" dynamically generate a CSS file - or "B" be able to read a css file and change certain attributes of the CSS classes in C#.

Reason being, I have site that is going to be configured to a user's company, utilizing their colors, logos, text sizes, etc...

The first thought was to dynamically create a CSS file - but I can't find anywhere on the net where anyone shows examples or whatnot.  The second thought was to read the css file and change the CSS classes based on a user's login.

Is there a simple way to do either?

Comment: Why do you need such a CSS file? Please consult an expert about your problem.

Comment: *CSS Preprocessors* were designed to dynamically generate CSS files.

Comment: Is it truly dynamic?  Or do you just need to pick between N possible choices, all of which could be pre-defined?

Comment: @AbdulMunim I thought that's why I posted here... Sorry to bother you.

Comment: @cimmanon That is a Good point.

Comment: @bwarner Yes, it's truly Dynamic - I will be pulling custom styles from a database table. - LIKE: Primary Accent Color, Primary Text Color, etc... I have CSS classes set up in four style sheets - loading each one based on "THEME", but not all of the users will be using one of the four - some users will have custom styles: Border Colors, etc, text colors, etc.  I know that I can add them, in the code behind, but that is a lengthy process - I didn't know if there was another way - perhaps changing the style in a default style sheet...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this is handled in a few different ways. You could include an additional or different CSS file based on properties of the request (e.g. current site). You could also output HTML that includes different classes based on request properties. A common technique is to add classes to root elements like  or  when certain conditions are met, and then write CSS to make use of those classes.

For example, if you are using the same code base for multiple sites, on site A you could have `<html class="site-a">` and on site B you'd have `<html class="site-b">`. Then you can override styles based on the site easily.

```
/* Default to white background */
body {
    background: white;
}

/* Use a black background for Site A */
.site-a body {
    background: black;
}

/* Use a blue background for Site B */
.site-b body {
    background: blue;
}
```

This is of course a very simple example. In the case of entire sites, separate CSS files makes more architectural sense, as you'd store them along with other site specific files.

I recommend studying more around how applications typically organize their front end presentation layers and files. For example, MVC is a way to separate out parts of an application. Within the context of presentation, you have concepts like templates and themes to encapsulate parts of the UI and turn it into reusable parts.

EDIT: Lost in my answer is that I didn't talk about actually dynamically generating CSS files. This is because dynamically generating CSS files is uncommon and generally not the right solution to a problem. As commentors have pointed out, there are CSS preprocessors like LESS and SASS which are generally targeted at solving some of CSSs internal issues (mostly redundancy). Preprocessors fix problems with CSS and are extremely useful, but aren't used in the way that it sounds like you've asked about. Separate CSS files or CSS files that key off of different classes and IDs are the solution, not dynamically creating a CSS file or block with different property values.

Comment: I'm kind of already doing that. I have four Style Sheets, that load based on a certain "theme" - but I need to be able to pull in custom values (Primary Accent Color[used for borders, background colors, etc], Secondary Accent Color, Primary Text Color, etc.).  As stated in a small comment above, I know that I can add styles to a control in the back-end, but if there was a way to read and pull in the css classes, then "modify" them with what's in the database table - if possible - THAT would be ideal.

Comment: I supposed your options would be 1) have a <link rel="stylesheet" href="/app/path/to/generate/css?site-id=A" media="all" /> element or similar. The path would be to a controller in your code that spits out a bit of CSS with the right settings. 2) Write the settings to disk when a user changes them and reference that CSS file when spitting out the page HTML (could incorporate LESS/SASS potentially). 3) Some combination of the previous options.